# Meaning of the extra apt-get options in early APT history

Tags: debian, apt

Following is the first few entries in `/var/log/apt/history.log` from a fresh installation of Debian 7.0:

```
Start-Date: 2013-05-09  20:02:18
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install locales
Install: locales:amd64 (2.13-38)
End-Date: 2013-05-09  20:02:19

Start-Date: 2013-05-09  22:03:06
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install busybox
Install: busybox:amd64 (1.20.0-7)
End-Date: 2013-05-09  22:03:07

Start-Date: 2013-05-09  22:03:07
Commandline: apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install initramfs-tools
Install: libklibc:amd64 (2.0.1-3.1, automatic), klibc-utils:amd64 (2.0.1-3.1, automatic), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.109.1)
End-Date: 2013-05-09  22:03:08
```

What is the meaning of these options:

```
-o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6
```

I cannot find them in the `apt-get` manpage.

Comment: Those are Perl lines, they look like variables being set to those values. Do you want to know what they are used for?

Comment: @slm It's not Perl, it's APT configuration syntax, and I think it's descended from C++ without going via Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those would be `debconf-apt-progress` descriptors. Used to display the progress bar when apt calls the `debconf-apt-progress` wrapper.
Output on File Descriptor 4, reserve File Descriptors 5 and 6.

`man 1 debconf-apt-progress`
debconf-apt-progress installs packages using debconf to display a progress bar.
The given command should be any command-line apt frontend; specifically, it must send progress information to the file descriptor selected by the `APT::Status-Fd` configuration option, and must keep the file descriptors nominated by the `APT::Keep-Fds` configuration option open when invoking debconf (directly or indirectly), as those file descriptors will be used for the debconf passthrough protocol.

You can find more about them in the `man -k apt` instead of `man apt-get.`

Comment: `man apt` makes no mention of `debconf-apt-progress`; it's almost a dummy manpage.

Comment: oops, that should have been `man -k apt`. there is some cruft to wade through but most of it has to do with `apt` or `aptitude` - I will edit